Does mediate() in R work with a multicategorical predictor?
My data is multilevel (multiple measures for each participant within each condition) with 3 conditions.
DV = continuous; Mediator = continuous; IV = categorical (with 3 conditions: control, condition A, condition B; within-ss).
For the IV, I created dummy variables (A = 0, 1; B = 0, 1; Control = 0, 1) for the analyses.
Does mediate() (in the "mediation" package) work with multicategorical predictors?
Analyses:
fit.mediator=lmer(Mediator ~ IV.A + IV.B + 
    (1 | id), data=data1)

summary(fit.mediator)

fit.dv=lmer(DV ~ IV.A + IV.B + Mediator + 
    (1 | id), data=data1)

summary(fit.dv)

summary(mediate(fit.mediator, fit.dv, 
    treat='IV.A', mediator='Mediator'))

summary(mediate(fit.mediator, fit.dv, 
    treat='IV.B', mediator='Mediator'))  

Is it appropriate for me to combine the results (indirect and direct effects) of the last two commands to show one combined mediation model with both IV's, the mediator, and the outcome variable?

Welcome to the site. This is more of a programming question, so you may have a better response on Stack Overflow

Questions solely about how software works are
off-topic
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you
understand the statistical concepts involved, the
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least
easy to get from the documentation.
